# "Object Not Found" ACL issue with Parse.com JS API

Tags: parse-platform

I'am modelling a "like" activity in the following way using Parse.com.

```
Activity object has 4 attributes
type: "like", "share" etc
fromUser: pointer to user who is liking
toUser: pointer to object's creator
object: pointer to the object liked.
```

After setting ACLs on the object,

When I try to save a "like" activity on an object someone else has created, 
I get an "object not found" error which I think is ACL related.

When saving a "like" activity on an object I created, all is fine.

Is there something wrong with the way I have modelled this activity?

Comment: This is not enough information to answer the question. What ACLs are you setting? Is it possible the object or toUser is dirty? What happens if you don't include the toUser field?

Comment: @bklimt Thankyou. After reading your comment I checked through my code and realised something was changed on the object making it dirty. Parse would try to save it and that is what was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

your Parse Object is dirty. Please clean it by calling the `revert()` function on the object before attaching it to another object.